# GAE Spending limit of 0$ valid?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is a 0$ spending limit valid and what does it mean ? According to some online articles this limit means you're using free quota only which is backed up by a message when you set the limit: "You are using free quota". However gcp support gave me contradictory answers, one saying the limit "does not work" and one saying 0$ means unlimited.

Edit:

Support1:

> The way our spending limits are set up needs to be above $0, our
>   spending limit will not work if you do not have an amount set up above
>   $0, that's why the project was not stopped.

Support2:

> it has been confirmed that setting a $0 as a Spending limit would be
>   the same as No Limits on your Spending limitations

They do indeed hint at the same thing, however the

> You are using the free quota

message is confusing me.

Comment: Did you setup billing and setup a payment method (credit ./ debit card)? Where do you live (country)? Please include the exact reply from Google in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley Billing enabled, app engine standard, Romania.

Comment: Now I understand what you are referring to. Spending limit of $0 means that you have not set a spending limit on GAE. If you want a spending limit set one. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Safety_Quotas_and_Billable_Quotas

Comment: Also, do not confuse "Spending Limit" with "Payment Method (Free Quota)".

Answer (score 0):

There are different kinds of limits applied for App Engine usage. According to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Safety_Quotas_and_Billable_Quotas),
Spending Limit is different from the Free Quotas.

> **Free quotas**: *Every application gets an amount of each resource for free. Free quotas can only be exceeded by paid applications, up to the application's spending limit or the safety limit, whichever applies first.*
>
> **Spending limits**: *If you are the project owner and the billing administrator, you can set the spending limit to manage application costs in the Google Cloud Platform Console in the App Engine Settings. Spending limits might be exceeded slightly as the application is disabled.*

The free quota is consumed first before being incurred with costs. Once you have exceeded the free quota, the pricing and usage cost will start to apply and the spending limit will be checked from this point forward.

If you set the Spending Limit to $0, this will be equivalent to limitless spending.